# Laravel. Простая выборка из трех связанных таблиц

Tags: laravel, laravel5

В базе три таблицы, вот модели:

```
class Day extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'day';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function weather()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('models\Weather');
    }
}

class Precipitation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'precipitation';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function weather()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('models\Weather');
    }
}

class Weather extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'weather';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function day()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('models\Day', 'models\Precipitation');
    }
}
```

Поля в таблице weather: id, name, day_id, precipitation_id
В остальных только id и name

Два вопроса:
1. Правильно ли я связал таблицы на уровне моделей?
2. Как написать обычный запрос на выборку из всех трех таблиц?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

```
class Weather extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'weather';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function day()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('models\Day');
    }

    public function precipitation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('models\Precipitation');
    }
}
```

2.

```
$weather = Weather::with(['day', 'precipitation'])->get();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Выбираю ваш ответ лучшим